# App keeps stopping when I try running it on phone (android studio)

Tags: android

I am getting an error when I run my android studio app on my phone. It says my app keeps stopping and won't load it.

Here is the error I got from the logs:

06-05 17:22:55.578 2715-2715/com.app.supermarketaislefinder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.supermarketaislefinder, PID: 2715
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.supermarketaislefinder/com.app.supermarketaislefinder.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.app.supermarketaislefinder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6676)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 207936012 byte allocation with 4154252 free bytes and 186MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:655)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1157)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:972)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:931)
        at android.view.View.(View.java:4226)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:603)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:599)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:595)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.(ConstraintLayout.java:565)

Thanks.

Comment: have you check your background image size ?

Comment: double check xml file for mainactivity, that is causing the error.

Comment: @MilanPansuriya it says 3040 × 1900... I'm guessing that's too big..

Comment: yes @Average_Coder please resize your image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a view inflation error, 
recheck what your inflating in your activity (R.id.activitylayouttoinflate)
try to CTRL+click it to reach the xml, 
and then check that xml for syntex error \ unsupported library.

post a different question for the second question you have.

Comment: Where do I find R.id.activitylayouttoinflat

Comment: Do I just look  in the activity_main.xml? There are no red underlines showing any error for me

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to figure it out and it works fine now. Thanks though :D